# Distinction between a "strictly typed function" and a "not strictly typed function"?

Tags: functions, category-theory, type-theory

Let $f$ be the identity function for the real numbers.

In the vernacular, we'd say that $f$ is a function from reals to reals, or that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.

Let $g$ be the inclusion map from the reals to the complex numbers. In the vernacular, we'd say that $g$ maps the reals to the complex numbers.

Now, in certain cases, as far as I can tell, it is useful to say that $f = g$. In fact, in set theory, they'd be the same object. However, in others, it is useful to consider $f$ and $g$ different objects -- after all, $f:\mathrm{Real}\to \mathrm{Real}$, and $g:\mathrm{Real}\to \mathrm{Complex}$ (which occurs a lot in programming languages with a richer typing system).

I'm not trying to argue which is better here, but is there a name for the *distinction* between these two different treatments of functions?

Comment: Pedantically, since $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2$, those two maps would not be the same in $\textbf{Set}$ (unless you compose $g$ with $\pi_1$).

Comment: @Metric Really? I'm pretty sure the standard definition of $\mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{R}'^2$, and then $\mathbb{R}$ is defined as a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ -- basically, yes, you first have to define something like $\mathbb{R}$, but then you hack it so that $\mathbb{R}\subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Yes, really. No, it's $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Metric http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmcomplex.html#axioms "We later define natural numbers, integers, and rational numbers as specific subsets of ℂ, leading to the nice relationships ℕ ⊂ ℤ ⊂ ℚ ⊂ ℝ ⊂ ℂ."

Comment: Which is not standard.

Comment: But then I'll probably have to define "standard" to make this a useful argument.